# Add loading circle animation while images are loaded

Tags: android, android-imageview, progressdialog

I already have a listview with images loaded from url. 
I want to add something like a spinning circle in **each image** while it is being loaded.
For now, i used i default as a replacement of the image being loaded before it is loaded.
What I mostly find here is that the have all classes extends AsyncTask. Well, what I have is this:

I have an Activity where parsing json is done.
Then i have a **MyCustomAdapter** which extends BaseAdapter:

```
    //constructor
    public MyCustomAdapter (Context c, List<RowItem> items){
    this.context = c;
    this.sRowItems = items;
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(c.getApplicationContext());
}
.
.
.

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prof_pic);



        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    RowItem sItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(sItem.getShopName());
    holder.txtDesc.setText(sItem.getShopDesc());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(sItem.getImageUrl(), holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}
```

Then i have my image loader class. So instead of AsyncTask, i used normal java threads.
part of it is this:

```
public class ImageLoader {

   MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
   FileCache fileCache;
   private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
   ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id=R.drawable.ic_launcher;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}
```

I saw answers here in stackoverflow to use

```
ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

But it didn't work with my code when i placed it in my ImageLoader class. 
Im having hard time implementing this loading animation circle.
Any help please. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a progressbar in each list item. Whenever you image gets downloaded, hide this progressbar[ set visibility GONE]. Your xml should look something

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgToBeSet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_cont_desc_common" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/imgProgress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgToBeSet"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/msg_download_failed" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Additionally i have a text view which is show if the download fails, in your case you can remove this text view and show the default image and hide the progressbar if download fails.

Answer (score 0):

in pre Execute:

```
ProgressDialog pd= new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
pd.setMessage("Please wait while Image lis being loaded");
pd.show();
```

in doInBackground():

```
pd.setMessage("Downloading image ....");
```

in postExecute:

```
pd.setMessage("");
pd.dismiss();
```

Comment: Use the Progressbar from Layout pallete into your xml like this:
    
XML:
     <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />     

    ProgressBar p =(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
    p.setEnabled(true);